# Add bash script as an entrypoint to Python package with Poetry

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-poetry

Is it possible to add `bash` script as an entrypoint (console script) to Python package via poetry? It looks like it only accepts python files ([see code here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/master/src/poetry/masonry/builders/editable.py#L31)).

I want `entry.sh` to be an entry script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

echo "Running entrypoint"
```

via `setup.py`

```py
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "entry=entry.sh",
        ],
    },
```

On the other hand `setuptools` *seems to be* supporting shell scripts ([see code here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/main/setuptools/command/easy_install.py#L814)).

Is it possible to include shell script into a package and add it to the entrypoints after installing when working with Poetry?

**UPD**. setuptools does not support that as well (it generates code below)

```
def importlib_load_entry_point(spec, group, name):
    dist_name, _, _ = spec.partition('==')
    matches = (
        entry_point
        for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
        if entry_point.group == group and entry_point.name == name
    )
    return next(matches).load()


globals().setdefault('load_entry_point', importlib_load_entry_point)
```

Is it design decision? It looks to me that packaging should provide such a feature to deliver complex applications as a single bundle.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the context of the code you've found: setuptools **creates** shell scripts; it doesn't create wrappers _around_ preexisting shell scripts. When you set `console_scripts.entry = mymodule.cli.entry:main`, you get a shell script created named `entry` (on Unixy systems), but that's a shell script that's responsible for starting the appropriate Python interpreter running the `mymodule.cli.entry` module's `main` function and passing its arguments through to it.

Comment: Why would python packaging provide an interface to a completely different language? And which shell? Some poor people run windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up using this workaround: have my script in place and add it to the bundle via `package_data` and call it from within Python code which I made as an entrypoint.

```py
import subprocess

def _run(bash_script):
    return subprocess.call(bash_script, shell=True)

def entrypoint():
    return _run("./scripts/my_entrypoint.sh")

def another_entrypoint_if_needed():
    return _run("./scripts/some_other_script.sh")
```

and `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
entrypoint = 'bash_runner:entrypoint'
another = 'bash_runner:another_entrypoint_if_needed'
```

Same works for `console_scripts` in `setup.py` file.

Comment: I have a very long and compute intense shell script (it's a pytorch distributed training, which use CPU and multiple GPU ). Will this workaround induce any overhead ?

Comment: @n0tis no, anyway you'll be invoking this script from somewhere. Think of it as a symlink being placed in the directory that is visible on your path, so you can just invoke it conveniently.